# jQuery() on a well-formed HTML string results in Syntax Error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a complete HTML document I'm pulling in with `$.ajax()`, and my `.done()` callback looks like this:

```
function (data, text_status, jq_xhr) {
  var $what_i_want = $(data).find('#what-i-want');
}
```

where `data` is a string that contains the entirety of a well-formed HTML document. This code never reaches `.find()`.

Upon `$(data)`, I get:

```
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <!DOCTYPE html>`...
```

The facts:

- I'm using jQuery 1.9.0
- The document is well-formed HTML5 according to the W3C validator.

I've used `jQuery()` to objectify many an HTML string, so I'm surprised this isn't working. Admittedly, I don't recall ever trying a whole document. Given the error, I'm guessing, perhaps, I need to escape this string somehow. But I'm not sure how.

Incidentally, **this works**:

```
var $what_i_want = $('#what-i-want', $.parseHTML(data))
```

But I can't figure out why the first approach fails.

Comment: I bet it's thinking that the document is not an HTML fragment, but a selector.  If you stripped out the DOCTYPE I bet it'd work :-)

Comment: Did you tried with $what_i_want = data.find('#what-i-want') too?

Comment: FYI http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring. This is somewhat related to your issue. But more for your reference. If you are returning a full html document this will cause other issues as well.

Comment: @Brian: hey, that's pretty interesting. Thanks for that link. Yeah, I don't think it's directly related, but it's definitely at least cursorily related. I feel like all signs point to the correct usages being `$(snippet_string)` and `$.parseHTML(document_string)`. I wonder what the "official" word is on when to use `$()` and when to use `$.parseHTML()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOCTYPE isn't an normal html tag; I think it would need to be removed.

It might have trouble with `body` as well, since you can't embed a whole document within another.  IIRC the internal method in jquery is just creating a span on the fly and updating the innerHTML.

Answer (score 15):

I had this same issue in a case where it was working on all sorts of other pages. They key for me was reading Brian's link on the upgrade-guide. The issue was this one page had a single blank line before the  so even though I was only attempting to insert a portion of the returned html, it was not considering the returned data to be html. From the upgrade guide

> As of 1.9, a string is only considered to be HTML if it starts with a less-than ("<") character.

Since it started with a blank line and not < it was not considered to be html. Thought I would add this contribution since I spent forever trying to figure out what the issue was.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: oye!  what an annoying bug...yes, i'm calling it a bug.  do you know if they change that in any other 1.9.X version?

Comment: This annoying solution works for me... `jQuery(jQuery.trim('  <stuff>  '))`