# Sphinx documentation generator search function hangs/fails

Tags: python, search, python-sphinx, ellipsis

I am using *Sphinx* to document my project. The project includes both reST files and Python API files. The built-in Java search function hangs frequently where it states "Searching..." with the ellipsis cycling from one period to three. It can find some words in the glossary and the index, but probably less than half of them. I can not find any documentation for this search function.  Unfortunately most searches for **Sphinx** and **search** result in links to the full-text search engine with the same name, *Sphinx*. What does the search engine look for and how can I make it work consistently?

Comment: Same thing is happening for me.  Check your browser console for javascript errors.  I see that "searchtools.js" is failing because "DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS" does not have a "SOURCELINK_SUFFIX" property...trying to figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old post but just update the **sphinx-rtd-theme** lib and you will be able to search.

See https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/pull/346

Comment: This comment remains valid in 2023

Comment: I did not recall writting this answer. Glad it helps someone years later :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably there can be different causes. Mine was that in searchtools.js, jQuery Ajax requests are used to get additional data from the found pages. This request returns the whole HTML document with an empty line before `<!DOCTYPE html>`. This caused an error when the other jQuery function creates a Node using this HTML document.
This case is discussed in [jQuery() on a well-formed HTML string results in Syntax Error, unrecognized expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103460/jquery-on-a-well-formed-html-string-results-in-syntax-error-unrecognized-expr).
Probably, it was necessary to update jQuery, but I had to work with the one shipped inside Sphinx.
So I solved it the next way:

1. Copied searchtools.js from the Sphinx base theme to my project `_static/` folder.
2. Edited there only one line by adding the trim() method (it was #283):  `var data = jqxhr.responseText.trim();`